# User agreement tick in REST API

Tags: rest

Usually in registration form there are a checkbox "Terms of use" or user agreement. So user cannot register if he not tick this checkbox.

Should we have a parameter in our API endpoint for this value or it is just on client side? Doe it has any legal issues?

Comment: I believe it has to be on client side, you can't take decisions from the user. Also I believe it can has some legal issues cause the user would say "I didn't accept this"

Comment: The question is more about that should the API require to pass the value true/false if terms was accepted or not

Comment: I don't think so, it should be a client side logic, if user didn't accept, you shouldn't let the user continue, so the client program doesn't need to call to your API.

Answer (score 0):

Terms of use can imply in legal issues for sure.

So, I understand that you need to know on the server side if the user accepted the terms of use or not when he makes his decision. The API could be something like:

```
PUT /users/{id}/terms
```

Body:

```
{
  "accepted": true
}
```

And I recommend to save additional Information of the user, like IP address, accepted date, etc.